# Dynamically replacing HTML with innerHTML not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a renderWorkoutUpdated function which takes in an object with updated values and the intention is to replace the particular workout record with the updated one.

```
_renderWorkoutUpdated(currentWorkout) {
    let html = `<li class="workout workout--${currentWorkout.type}" data-id="${
      currentWorkout.id
    }">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="workout__title">
        ${currentWorkout.description}
        </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="kebab-menu">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>        
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownContent">
        <div class="option">Edit</div>
        <div class="option">Delete</div>
        <div class="option">Delete All</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>       
    
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">${
        currentWorkout.type === 'running' ? '' : ''
      }</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.distance}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
    </div>
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.duration}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
    </div>`;

    if (currentWorkout.type === 'running')
      html += `
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.pace.toFixed(1)}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">min/km</span>
    </div>
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon"></span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.cadence}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">spm</span>
    </div>
  </li>`;

    if (currentWorkout.type === 'cycling')
      html += `
    <div class="workout__details">
    <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
    <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.speed.toFixed(1)}</span>
    <span class="workout__unit">km/h</span>
  </div>
  <div class="workout__details">
    <span class="workout__icon">⛰</span>
    <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.elevationGain}</span>
    <span class="workout__unit">m</span>
  </div>
</li> `;

    document.querySelector(
      `.workout[data-id="${currentWorkout.id}"]`
    ).innerHTML = html;
  }
```

The updated form looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZKda.png). The first record is the updated one and it should look like the 2nd and 3rd record i.e. not create another container within the container. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace the element with the new HTML. But you're nesting the new HTML *inside* the element, not replacing it.

Comment: So, just use `outerHTML` instead and it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the new `<li>` *inside* the old `<li>`, but I think you want to replace one with the other.

Simply leave out the `<li>` tag in `html`, just put the new contents there. If you need to change attributes of the existing element, do that separately.

```js
_renderWorkoutUpdated(currentWorkout) {
  let html = `<div class="container">
        <div class="workout__title">
        ${currentWorkout.description}
        </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="kebab-menu">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>        
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdownContent">
        <div class="option">Edit</div>
        <div class="option">Delete</div>
        <div class="option">Delete All</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>       
    
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">${
        currentWorkout.type === 'running' ? '' : ''
      }</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.distance}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
    </div>
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.duration}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
    </div>`;

  if (currentWorkout.type === 'running')
    html += `
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.pace.toFixed(1)}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">min/km</span>
    </div>
    <div class="workout__details">
      <span class="workout__icon"></span>
      <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.cadence}</span>
      <span class="workout__unit">spm</span>
    </div>
  </li>`;

  if (currentWorkout.type === 'cycling')
    html += `
    <div class="workout__details">
    <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
    <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.speed.toFixed(1)}</span>
    <span class="workout__unit">km/h</span>
  </div>
  <div class="workout__details">
    <span class="workout__icon">⛰</span>
    <span class="workout__value">${currentWorkout.elevationGain}</span>
    <span class="workout__unit">m</span>
  </div> `;

  let curWorkout =
    document.querySelector(
      `.workout[data-id="${currentWorkout.id}"]`
    );
  curWorkout.innerHTML = html;
  curWorkout.className = `workout workout-${currentWorkout.type}`;
}
```